# Concurrency issue with writing batches via AIOFile - output file data getting corrupted

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm having trouble concurrently writing to a couple of files. I tried adding locks to prevent a race condition on the writes, and I verified that the data is valid when it enters the `write_batches` method, but when I check the data in either of the output files, it's all messed up. It appears that each write step is partially writing over the writes of a separate thread, so I get output where the first part of each line is randomly chopped up. Between invocations of `write_and_flush(..)`, I'm noticing that the contents of the output file are getting overwritten as well, so it seems like a combination of a concurrency issue and something I'm overlooking with the behavior of the write path.

Any ideas?

```
import unittest

from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

from core.ChainFactory import ChainFactory
import asyncio
from aiofile import AIOFile
import pandas as pd


async def process_data(model, factory):
    # Read the file
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "sitemap_data_raw",
        header=None,
        names=["Record"],
        engine="python",
        on_bad_lines="warn",
    )
    # Deduplicate the contents
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Create locks for file writing to ensure exclusive access
    q_lock = asyncio.Lock()
    a_lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def process_batch(rows):
        # Process a batch of rows concurrently
        tasks = [
            factory.build_qa_chain(model).ainvoke({"chunk": row.Record}) for row in rows
        ]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    async def write_and_flush(writer, text, lock):
        async with lock:  # Ensure exclusive access to the writer
            await writer.write(text)
            await writer.fsync()  # Ensure data is written and synchronized to disk

    # Define a function to write batches to files, using different parameter names to avoid shadowing
    async def write_batches(question_writer, answer_writer, results):
        # Flatten results and write questions and answers to their respective files
        for my_result in results:
            for my_record in my_result:
                await write_and_flush(
                    question_writer, my_record["question"] + "\n", q_lock
                )
                await write_and_flush(answer_writer, my_record["answer"] + "\n", a_lock)

    # Open the output files
    async with AIOFile("question_output.txt", "w") as q_writer, AIOFile(
        "answer_output.txt", "w"
    ) as a_writer:
        batch_size = 10
        for i in range(0, len(df), batch_size):
            batch_rows = df.iloc[i : i + batch_size].itertuples(index=False)
            batch_results = await process_batch(batch_rows)
            await write_batches(q_writer, a_writer, batch_results)


class TestDataPrep(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_prepare_qa_dataset(self):
        # Read sitemap_data_raw
        model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106")
        factory = ChainFactory()
        # Run the async function
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(process_data(model, factory))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving to `aiofiles` (instead of `aiofile`) and changing the lock structure:

```
import unittest

from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

from core.ChainFactory import ChainFactory
import asyncio
import aiofiles
import pandas as pd


async def process_data(model, factory):
    # Read the file
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "sitemap_data_raw",
        header=None,
        names=["Record"],
        engine="python",
        on_bad_lines="warn",
    )
    # Deduplicate the contents
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    # Create locks for file writing to ensure exclusive access
    file_lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def process_batch(rows):
        # Process a batch of rows concurrently
        tasks = [
            factory.build_qa_chain(model).ainvoke({"chunk": row.Record}) for row in rows
        ]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    # Define a function to write batches to files, using different parameter names to avoid shadowing
    async def write_batches(question_file, answer_file, results):
        # Flatten results and write questions and answers to their respective files
        for my_result in results:
            for my_record in my_result:
                async with file_lock:
                    await question_file.write(my_record["question"] + "\n")
                    await answer_file.write(my_record["answer"] + "\n")

    # Open the output files
    async with aiofiles.open("question_output.txt", "w") as q_file, aiofiles.open(
        "answer_output.txt", "w"
    ) as a_file:
        batch_size = 1000
        for i in range(0, len(df), batch_size):
            batch_rows = df.iloc[i : i + batch_size].itertuples(index=False)
            batch_results = await process_batch(batch_rows)
            await write_batches(q_file, a_file, batch_results)


class TestDataPrep(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_prepare_qa_dataset(self):
        # Read sitemap_data_raw
        model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106")
        factory = ChainFactory()
        # Run the async function
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(process_data(model, factory))
```